# Matrix tensor indices

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products, tensors

Suppose I have an orthonormal basis 
$$B = \left \{ u_{i}  \right \}_{i=1}^{\infty}$$

Then for a matrix $K$, do I represent it as 
$$K = \sum_{j,k=0}^{\infty}k_{jk}\left ( u_{i}\bigotimes u_{j} \right )$$

or

$$K = \sum_{j,k=0}^{\infty}k_{jk}\left ( u^{i}\bigotimes u^{j} \right )\ ?$$

I'm inclined to believe the second form is correct. However, my notes stipulates the first one to be correct—quite possibly a blunder on the author's end.

Clarifications would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of convention that differs between literatures and depending on what you're doing.  If you're going to use raised indices in a meaningful way, then I'd expect to see the basis written as
$$ B = \{ u^i \}_{i=1}^{\infty} $$
with the index up on vectors.  Then your second option for $K$ would be correct.  Since you wrote the vectors in the basis with index down, it seems like you're in a convention where all indices are down and the first option is correct.

Comment: It's strange. Outer product operation necessarily involves one column vector and one row vector. By convention, if the column vector denotes the set of tangent vectors and the row column denotes the set of normal vectors- where the column vector has a subscript and the row vector a superscript, then how is it possible for the outer product in the OP to have superscripts and subscripts both at the same time?

Comment: @Mathematicing I'm not used to seeing that circle-x notation and index notation together. If you're sure that it means "outer product" ($uu^T$ in vector notation) in your book, then it probably means mixed indices $u^i u_j$. I took it to mean tensor product between vectors, which I would write as $u^i u^j$. Whichever is correct here, the indices on $K$ should be written consistently.

Answer (score 0):

This depends very much on convention.  If the basis is indexed by lower indices, the tensor product should be lower indices too.  One could write the coefficients with upper indices and omit the summation sign like so: $$K = k^{ij}e_i\otimes e_j.$$  That would be the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) which is quite popular in mathematical physics.  You can also [read more about conventions with upper and lower indices here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_and_lowering_indices).  In total the answer is "it depends" on the conventions made in the book you are reading, and also on the field you are working in.  Mathematicians usually don't use summation convention.